# Best way to forward a collection of emails from Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a collection of emails detailing work I have done for a recent project and I need to send all of these emails to someone.  What would be the best way to do this using Outlook?  Should I create the email then just add each email individually as an attachment, or is there a better way of grouping all of the emails together into a single attachment?

Comment: Are you looking for a **server side** for a **client side** rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the messages you want to forward, and click Forward.  It should bulk-attach them for you.

Regardless of how you do it, unless you are able to redirect each message individually, its going to be a pain for the person on the other end to get what they need out of the messages.

If you’re on Exchange, it may be better to try and set up a public folder and copy the messages there, then let the other person pull them into their mailbox.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not on exchange. I need to get all my emails from my home account to another account at my work.

Comment: Can you map your work account from the same outlook instance?  Then you can just drag the messages from one inbox to the other (or any other folder)

Comment: Why is it a "pain for the person on the other end"? Outlook should attach the messages as separate messages, and the recipient should be able to drag them out into a folder again. At least that's how I remember it...

Comment: If you're talking 10 messages, no pain at all. If you're talking a couple of thousand, or ten thousand, then its a pain.

Comment: It seems that (at least in Outlook 2010), the recipient can select the email received from you (the one with thousands of attachments forwarded) and go to "File -> Save attachments", then select a folder where all the attachments (.msg files) will be saved.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good link which explains how to get this task done easily. It is a bit of trick but still can be done.

http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_forward_fold.htm

1. Create a new folder. (Call it "Forward" perhaps.)
2. Copy all messages you want to forward to the "Forward" folder.
3. Make sure the "Forward" folder is open.
4. Select Tools | Rules and Alerts... from the menu.
5. Click New Rule....
6. Highlight Check messages when they arrive.
7. Click Next >.
8. Click Next > again, leaving all conditions unchecked.
9. Click Yes.
10. Make sure forward it to people or distribution list is checked under Step 1: Select action(s).
11. You can alternatively check forward it to people or distribution list as an attachment to forward messages not inline but attached.
12. Click people or distribution list under Step 2: Edit the rule description.
13. Double-click the desired contact or list from your address book, or type the email address to which you want to forward under To ->.
14. Click OK.
15. Click Next >.
16. Click Next > again.
17. Make sure Turn on this rule is not checked under Step 2: Setup rule options.
18. Now make sure Run this rule now on messages already in "Forward" (if you named the folder "Forward").
19. Click Finish.

Comment: This is just fabulous! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your answers none of them hit the spot for me..... so I added both accounts as IMAP accounts to Outlook.

Then just drag and drop the emails from one inbox to the other! Done!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a .PST file with required emails. Assuming the .PST file is not too big, and the recipient is also using outlook, zip it up with 7zip as a .7z and send. If they don't know how to open the .pst it's as easy as file, open outlook data file. I always find that forwarding a bulk of emails is very difficult to sort/sift through as it only appears by subject, not sender or date etc.

Be very careful NOT to drag and drop the emails to the newly created PST or outlook will move them from your inbox to the PST. drag and drop with the right mouse button instead, and when you let go you will be given a small submenu to move,copy or cancel. Select copy.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in Outlook Express if the recipient is willing to assist you a little. You should consider this solution only if you have substantial number of emails you want to forward.

Do the following (Assuming the recipient(s) also are using OE):

1: Create a temporary folder in OE and call it, i.e. 'BulkMailFromCharles'.

2: Move or copy the all mails you want to forward into this folder.

3: Close OE.

4: Copy the file BulkMailFromCharles.dbx from your Outlook Express system folder, usually found under 'C:\Documents and Settings....' to i.e. C:\TEMP

5: Launch Outlook Express

6: Send the file C:\TEMP\BulkMailFromCharles.dbx to the recipient(s).

7: Instruct each recipient to do the following:

8: - Create in their OE a new folder with name i.e. BulkMailFromCharles.

9: - Store the received file BulkMailFromCharles.dbx in i.e. C:\TEMP

10: - Copy any single file from any other folder, i.e. 'Inbox' to the new folder 'BulkMailFromCharles'

11: - Close OE.

12: - Copy or move C:\TEMP\BulkMailFromCharles.dbx to the OE system folder, usually found under 'C:\Documents and Settings....'

13: - Open OE

14: - The bulk mails should now be in the new folder BulkMailFromCharles.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just documenting the emails, you could make a Word document and drag each email into the document where it will appear as an icon labeled with the email's subject. You can also add text/captions in the Word file to group or explain the emails, or group/arrange them in some logical order (for example, under headings like 'Phase I of Project', 'Phase II', etc.). When you send the Word document to the recipient, they can click on an icon and that email will open up in their Outlook. 
This approach would only be appealing if the number of emails was reasonable (my tolerance would be <50) and there was a benefit to the recipient in organizing them.